# Polyfill for crossorigin attribute

Tags: internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I would like to use the [crossorigin attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_settings_attributes) on a script tag. Unfortunately my app has to support IE11 which doesn't support this feature. Does anyone know a polyfill for it? I couldn't find anything about it...

Comment: As far as I know, there doesn't contains this Polyfill.